# can't change page size from 8.5 x 11 to 6 x 9

Tags: r, bookdown

In the bookdown krantz.cls example, there is this code where it says to uncomment to get a 6x9 book:

```
%%%Uncomment to get 6x9 trim
%%%%\textheight = 43pc
%%%%  %\advance\textheight by \topskip
%%%%\addtolength\textheight{3pt}
%%%%  \textwidth 26pc
%%%%\addtolength\textwidth{.5pt}
%%%% \topmargin0in
%%%%  \oddsidemargin1.1875in
%%%%  \evensidemargin1.1875in
%%%%  \htrim5.05pc
%%%%  \vtrimtop7.7pc
%%%%  \vtrimbot5.44pc
%%%%%  \hoffset-5pt
%%%%  \voffset45pt
%%%%\let\normaltextheight\textheight
```

Despite doing this, I am unable to get the book to print to pdf as 6x9. Instead, it renders as 8.5 x 11

I tried uncommenting the code below where it says to Uncomment to get a 6x9 trim.

Comment: here is where the krantz.cls is located: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/krantz.cls